# Add a URL prefix to permalinks of one category of posts only

Tags: categories, permalinks

I have the permalink structure http://domain.com/%postname%/, which is what I want to keep for most of my posts, however there is one category of posts that I would like to move from http://domain.com/%postname%/ to http://domain.com/articles/%postname%/.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this for that one category of posts without changing the URLs of all the other posts?

Comment: Although you can do that (see @Dan's answer, I think it is correct), What you really need is a custom post type, I think.

Comment: If you need this also for all the normal post's rewrite rules (content pagination, feed, archive, ... ) then it's a good idea from @cybmeta to use a custom post type for articles otherwise you could check out the approach in Dan's answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest making the `post` type `hierarchical` so you could set a parent post, but having tried it... it still redirects `/articles/%postname%/` back to `/%postname%/` for reasons I have yet to fathom... I can't see any other difference in the post type objects for `page` and `post`. strange, anyone with clues on that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose `articles` is slug of the category.

#### 1. Add a custom rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^articles/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}, 10, 0);
```

#### 2. Filter the post link:

```
add_filter('post_link', function($post_link, $post, $leave_name = false, $sample = false)
{
    if ( has_category('articles', $post) ) {
        $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_name, '/articles/' . $post->post_name, $post_link);
    }

    return $post_link;

}, 10, 4);
```

That's all. Try it out in your `functions.php` and remember to flush your permalink structure.

**References**:

- [post_link filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/)

Comment: I think you can simplify this further with a [`has_category()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src//wp-includes/category-template.php#L1281) check, that's a wrapper for  `has_term( $category, 'category', $post )`. There's also the old  [`in_category()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src//wp-includes/category-template.php#L257) that's a wrapper for `has_category()`.

Comment: @birgire You rock! I have learnt from you a lot :)

Comment: I'm just trying to pass on what I've learnt from this great community ;-) ps: just a note regarding the string replacement: if the post's slug is contained in the domain name then we will have a problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I changed http://domain.com/%postname%/ to http://domain.com/news/%postname%/. But I am having issues with categories under NEWS itself. How can I make this work for sub-categories