# Add a URL prefix to permalinks of News category and sub-categories of posts only

Tags: permalinks, urls

I changed http://domain.com/%postname%/ to http://domain.com/news/%postname%/ using the answer provided here: [Add a URL prefix to permalinks of one category of posts only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215263/add-a-url-prefix-to-permalinks-of-one-category-of-posts-only). But I am having issues with categories under NEWS itself. How can I make this work for sub-categories

Comment: For complex modifications to URL strictures you'll likely need to amend WordPress' rewrite rules. In order to help anyone answering you should post an example of the URL structure you would ideally have.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_category_base' );
function wpa_category_base() {
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
        // The resulting internal URL
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',

        // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
        'top' );
}
```

Custom permalink structure: /media/%category%/%postname%/ Category base: .

Worked for me, WordPress 3.4.1, without any related plugins.

Try

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_category_base' );
function wp_category_base() {
// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/][^f][^e][^e][^d]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', //here my changes to exclude 'feed'
    // The resulting internal URL
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
    // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
    'top' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. SHould I add the above code together with the other 2 provided here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215263/add-a-url-prefix-to-permalinks-of-one-category-of-posts-only ?